# Scala the "magic" of implementing assertion during compilation instead of runtime

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, generic-programming, shapeless

Currently, I am learning generic or meta programming in Shapeless. I am facinated about the feature which can check the logic during compilation instead of runtime. There are 2 amazing examples:
1. Checksum: https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/3763016
2. TowersOfHanoi: https://gist.github.com/jrudolph/66925

However, I think those 2 examples thrust me so quickly into the deeper areas of this feature. Only I know so far is some tricks as follow:

1: define the context bound to use implicit to make sure class has correct constraint. I think that is reason we have to lift some primitive types into class type like int, so compiler know what type is (I am not sure about my argument). Code:

```
object bla {
  implicitly[A <:< B]
}
```

2: using macros.

Are there other magic tricks to fulfill that ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I've got a more detailed walkthrough of the first example [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/09/learning-shapeless/). This question is pretty vague, though—I'd suggest taking some problem that you know how to solve at the value level, trying to solve it at the type level, and asking more focused questions when you run into trouble.